# How do I authenticate to Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server with a Personal Access Token?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, restful-authentication

From PowerShell, how do I use Personal Access Tokens (PAT) to authenticate to my Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) account or on-premises Team Foundation Server (TFS)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[As of July 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015/2015-jul-7-vso), Visual Studio Online allows users to create **Personal Access Tokens** (PAT) as a more secure option than **alternate credentials**.

To authenticate to the [REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/overview), all you need to do is use the PAT as the password portion in a **Basic Auth** HTTP Header along with your REST request.

```
$personalAccessToken = "your-personal-access-token-here"
$uri = "https://your-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=1.0&ids=1,2,3,4"

Invoke-RestMethod `
-Uri $uri `
-Headers @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)")) }
```

Note, that the **username** portion of the Basic Auth header is completely ignored when you use a personal access token. You could have `("BLAHBLAH:$($personalAccessToken)"))` instead and it will still work fine.

Comment: can i use them in TFS ?

Comment: yes. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=tfs-2018

Comment: what happens to this part https://your-account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/ ? tried every combination i was unable to do code search