# Using Token to get authorized for VSTS API, but status.code = 203

Tags: python, http-headers, azure-devops, token, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use API of VSTS 5.0, but I get 203 when I try to use Token with python.

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Authorization': b'Basic '+ base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8')),
    'content-type': 'application/json',}

def get_page_list():
    url = 'https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify = False)
        print (response.status_code)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
    except requests.ConnectionError as e:
        print('Error*****', e.args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    json = get_page_list()
    print(json)
```

And this will return to this: 203 None

I really can't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: What's the module do you use for your python file? Can you show the whole content here? And what if you use urllib.request module as Cece said?

Comment: And it seems you are using Ajax requests, actually you can use REST API directly.

Comment: I use urllib.request. I don't know exactly how to use API, so I use a lot of json.get(). Could you please tell me how to use api with a simple example?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192108/authenticating-to-visualstudioonline-rest-api-with-personal-access-token-using-p You need to add a colon preceding colon **:** in PAT before base64 encoding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we find this way to get authorization:

```
    try:
    response = requests.get(url1, headers=headers, verify = False,auth = (MyToken,''))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print('Error', e.args)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your PAT is valid, and the api version you use should be `4.0`. You could also try the code snippet in this case: [Authenticating to VisualStudioOnline REST API with Personal Access Token using Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192108/authenticating-to-visualstudioonline-rest-api-with-personal-access-token-using-p):

```
import json
import base64
import urllib.request

personal_access_token = ":xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

headers = {}
headers['Content-type'] = "application/json"
headers['Authorization'] = b'Basic ' + 
base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8'))

instance = "mycompany.visualstudio.com"
project = "MyProject"
repository ="MyRepository"
pullrequest = "3468"
api_version = "3.0"

repositories_url = ("https://%s/DefaultCollection/%s/_apis/projects?
api-version=%s" % (instance, project, api_version))
print(repositories_url)

request = urllib.request.Request(repositories_url, headers=headers)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
response = opener.open(request)
print(response.read())
```

Comment: Thanks~ It's 4.0 and I find another way to get authorized.