# Using HTTR POST to Create a Azure Devops Work Item

Tags: r, azure, rest, azure-devops

Im attempting to setup some R code to create a new work item task in Azure Devops. Im okay with a mostly empty work item to start with if thats okay to do (my example code is only trying to create a work item with a title).

I receive a 203 response but the work item doesn't appear in Devops.

Ive been following this documentation from Microsoft, I suspect that I might be formatting the body incorrectly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Ive tried updating different fields and formatting the body differently with no success. I have attempted to create either a bug or feature work item but both return the same 203 response.

To validate that my token is working I can GET work item data by ID but the POST continues to return a 203.

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)

url <- 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=5.1'

headers = c(
    'Authorization' = sprintf('basic %s',token),
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json-patch+json',
    'Host' = 'dev.azure.com'
  )

data <- toJSON(list('body'= list("op"= "add",
                                   "path"= "/fields/System.AreaPath",
                                   "value"= "Sample task")), auto_unbox = TRUE, pretty = TRUE)

res <- httr::POST(url,
                  httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
                  httr::verbose(),
                  body = data)
```

Im expecting a 200 response (similar to the example in the link above) and a work item task in Azure DevOps Services when I navigate to the website.

Im not the best with R so please be detailed. Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is fairly old, but I cannot seem to find a good solution posted yet. So, I will add my solution in case others find themselves in this situation. Note, this did take some reading through other SO posts and trial-and-error.

Mengdi is correct that you do need to convert your token to a Base64 string.

Additionally, Daniel from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192108/authenticating-to-visualstudioonline-rest-api-with-personal-access-token-using-p) pointed out that:

> In my experience with doing this via other similar mechanisms, you have to include a leading colon on the PAT, before base64 encoding.

Mengdi came up big in [another SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524419/azure-devops-api-invalid-patch-document)

> Please try with adding [{ }] outside your request body.

From there, I just made slight modifications to your `headers` and `data` objects. Removed `'body'` from your json, and made use of paste to add square brackets as well. I found that the `Rcurl` package made base64 encoding a breeze. Then I was able to successfully create a blank ticket (just titled) using the API! Hope this helps someone!

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)  

#user and PAT for api
userid <- ''
token= 'whateveryourtokenis'    

url <- 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$bug?api-version=5.1'    

#create a combined user/pat
#user id can actually be a blank string
#RCurl's base64 seemed to work well
c_id <- RCurl::base64(txt = paste0(userid,
                                   ":",
                                   devops_pat 
                                   ),
                       mode = "character"
                      )

#headers for api call
headers <- c(
             "Authorization" = paste("Basic",
                                      c_id,
                                      sep = " "
             ),
             'Content-Type' = 'application/json-patch+json',
             'Host' = 'dev.azure.com' 
             )

#body
data <- paste0("[",
               toJSON(list( "op"= "add",
                            "path"= "/fields/System.Title",
                            "value"= "API test - please ignore"), 
                      auto_unbox = TRUE, 
                      pretty = TRUE
                     ),
                "]"
              )

#make the call
res <- httr::POST(url,
                  httr::add_headers(.headers=headers),
                  httr::verbose(),
                  body = data
                  )

#check status
status <- res$status_code

#check content of response
check <- content(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The POST continues to return a 203.

The HTTP response code `203` means `Non-Authoritative Information`, it should caused by your token format is converted incorrectly.

> If you wish to provide the personal access token through an HTTP
>   header, you must first convert it to a Base64 string.

Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#assemble-the-request) described, if you want to use VSTS rest api, you must convert your token to a `Base64` string. But in your script, you did not have this script to achieve this convert.

So, please try with the follow script to convert the token to make the key conformant with the requirements(load the **base64enc package** first):

```
require(base64enc)
key <- token
keys <- charToRaw(paste0(key,":token"))
auth <- paste0("Basic ",base64encode(keys))
```

Hope this help you get 200 response code

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ill give this a try later today and provide feedback! I appreciate your help.

Comment: I appreciate your response and suggestion but by encoding the token to use the base64encode function I now get a 400 response code. Im a little unclear on what a VSTS rest API is but I assume that is what I am working with so Ill do some more research on this. If you have any other suggestions please let me know. (Ive pasted the response below) Thanks again!

 Date: 2019-08-26 15:18
  Status: 400
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 459 B

Comment: Response code 400 means the Bad request. This means the token is correct but your request body has error. I will update my answer after check it on my side. In addition, where did you run these R script?