# Azure DevOps API - Invalid Patch Document

Tags: php, laravel, azure-devops, guzzle, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to connect to the Azure Dev Ops API using PHP, Guzzle and Laravel.  I am able to successfully connect and GET a workitem with the below code:

```
Route::get('/getworkitem', function() {

    $response = Http::withBasicAuth('Username', 'PAT')
    ->get('https://dev.azure.com/{Organisation}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/32?fields=System.WorkItemType,System.AssignedTo&$expand=Links&api-version=5.1');

    return $response;

});
```

I am trying to do a POST request using the Laravel HTTP Client to create a new work item with the below code:

```
Route::get('/add', function() {

    $requiredata = array (
            'op' => 'add',
            'path' => '/fields/System.Title',
            'from' => null,
            'value' => 'Sample Task'
    );

    $response = Http::withBasicAuth('Username', 'PAT')->withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json-patch+json',
        ])->post('https://dev.azure.com/Oraganisation/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$issue?api-version=5.1', [
            'body' => json_encode($requiredata,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
        ]);

        dd(json_decode($response->getBody()));
});
```

However, when I run this I am getting the below response:

```
+"$id": "1"
+"innerException": null
+"message": "You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request."
+"typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common"
+"typeKey": "VssPropertyValidationException"
+"errorCode": 0
+"eventId": 3000
```

To me this means that the 'op' in the body of the response is incorrect but when I check it is sending the correct information.

I then tried to do the request through Guzzle with the below:

```
Route::get('/add2', function() {

    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json-patch+json',
    ];

    $body = [
            'op' => 'add',
            'path' => '/fields/System.Title',
            'from' => null,
            'value' => 'Sample Task'
    ];
    $body = json_encode($body,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    $client = new Client();

    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://dev.azure.com/{Organisation}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Issue?api-version=5.1', [
        'auth' => 'Username', 'Password'
    ], $headers, $body);

    dd(json_decode($res->getBody()));

});
```

This gives a return of null.

I've been able to get the POST request to work in Postman, but not in PHP. I have gone through Google and found nothing that would point to something that I have done incorrectly but if someone would be able to point me in the right direction to why it is working as a GET but not with a POST that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What was the solution? I'm running into it with C# right now!

Answer (score 1):

Please try with adding **[{ }]** outside your request body.

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": "null",
    "value": "sample task"
  }
]
```

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException

This error message represents out system could not handle the body property successfully. As normal, user must sent request body with correct property, so that our system can read successfully. Then parsing its contents, like `'op'`, `'path'` and etc.

Comment: Hi Merlin,

I've had a look at the output of $requiredata and $body and the format of it is coming out exactly as you've specified. I changed

'body' => json_encode($requiredata,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)

to just be without 'body' => and I got the error: At least one operation is required for apply. Does this mean the body is now being read or is this a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the encoding on the content type.

`ContentType "application/json-patch+json; charset=utf-8"`

I had the same issue with foreign characters

Answer (score -1):

The code below is a solution.

```
Route::get('/add_work_item',
    function() {

        $response = Http::withBasicAuth('{key}', '{PAT}')
        ->withHeaders(
            [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json-patch+json'
            ]
        )
        ->post('https://dev.azure.com/{Organisation}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=5.1', 
        [
            
            [
                'op' => 'add',
                'path' => '/fields/System.Title',
                'from' => null,
                'value' => 'New Task'
            ],

            [
                'op'=> 'add',
                'path'=> '/fields/System.AreaPath',
                'from'=> null,
                'value'=> '{Project}'
            ]

        ]
        );

        dd(json_decode($response->getBody()));
    }
);
```