# Azure DevOps REST API returning HTTP Status 203 when using Python Requests

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, python-requests

[I saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56593061/2009612) about Python `requests` attempting to authenticate to Azure DevOps REST API and receiving HTTP Status 203, Non-Authoritative Information. When viewing the text response, its just the HTML of the login page and not actually logging me in. I used the `Authorization: Basic <BASE64 PAT>` [listed on their REST API page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#assemble-the-request), but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code example:

```py
"""Using Python and Requests to interact with Azure DevOps REST API
"""


import base64
import pprint as pp
import requests


with open('ado_pat.txt', 'r') as file:
    PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN = file.read().replace('\n', '')

PAT_BASE_64 = base64.b64encode(
    b'{PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN}').decode('ascii')
COLLECTION = 'collection_name'
ORGANIZATION_URL = f'https://dev.azure.com/{COLLECTION}'
RESOURCE_PATH = '/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1'
HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {PAT_BASE_64}',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

try:
    ADO_RESPONSE = requests.get(
        ORGANIZATION_URL + RESOURCE_PATH, headers=HEADERS)

    pp.pprint(ADO_RESPONSE)
    pp.pprint(ADO_RESPONSE.text)
    ADO_RESPONSE.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    pp.pprint(err)
```

This is the response that I get:

```
<Response [203]>
(''\r\n'
```

Then it displays the whole login page. I would use the [microsoft/azure-devops-python-api](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/README.md) but I don't really understand or see the methods I can call nor really understand how that works.

--EDIT WORKING EXAMPLE --

This example works now.

```py
"""Using Python and Requests to interact with Azure DevOps REST API
"""


import base64
import pprint as pp
import requests


with open('ado_pat.txt', 'r') as file:
    PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN = file.read().replace('\n', '')

USERNAME = ""
USER_PASS = USERNAME + ":" + PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
B64USERPASS = base64.b64encode(USER_PASS.encode()).decode()

COLLECTION = 'collection_name'
ORGANIZATION_URL = f'https://dev.azure.com/{COLLECTION}'
RESOURCE_PATH = '/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1'
HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % B64USERPASS
}

try:
    ADO_RESPONSE = requests.get(
        ORGANIZATION_URL + RESOURCE_PATH, headers=HEADERS)

    pp.pprint(ADO_RESPONSE)
    pp.pprint(ADO_RESPONSE.text)
    ADO_RESPONSE.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    pp.pprint(err)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a personal access token for azure devops API repository manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58592919/using-a-personal-access-token-for-azure-devops-api-repository-manipulation)

Comment: I'll update my code to the working version. What I really got is that the M$ example didn't actually work, and isn't very good.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Accepted. I had looked at it before but I needed to wait longer than other things came up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting 203 with error when using vsts rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913656/getting-203-with-error-when-using-vsts-rest-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Using a comment's link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58592919/2009612), I was able to get the code above working. This is the end result working code.

```py
"""Using Python and Requests to interact with Azure DevOps REST API
"""


import base64
import json
import pprint as pp
import requests


with open('ado_pat.txt', 'r') as file:
    PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN = file.read().replace('\n', '')

USERNAME = ""
USER_PASS = USERNAME + ":" + PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN
B64USERPASS = base64.b64encode(USER_PASS.encode()).decode()

COLLECTION = 'collection_name'
ORGANIZATION_URL = f'https://dev.azure.com/{COLLECTION}'
RESOURCE_PATH = '/_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=5.1'
HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % B64USERPASS
}

try:
    ADO_RESPONSE = requests.get(
        ORGANIZATION_URL + RESOURCE_PATH, headers=HEADERS)

    pp.pprint(ADO_RESPONSE)
    pp.pprint(ADO_RESPONSE.text)
    ADO_RESPONSE.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    pp.pprint(err)


with open('output.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(ADO_RESPONSE.json(), indent=4))
```

It seems that the API docs didn't specify how to encode the PAT properly and needed to be reworked.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  must have this this colon: 
USERNAME + ":" + PERSONAL_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN

Answer (score 1):

*you can also do this*

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.post(
url=your_link, 
auth=HTTPBasicAuth("", PAT),
headers=headers
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone because I have been struggling for hours, I was running the code from GitLab runners and pulling the PAT from the CI/CD variables. It turns out, when variables are set to protected and/or masked, this messes up the encoding and the PAT becomes incorrectly encoded. Disabling the protection and masking fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to do it via Rest Client vscode extension.
My mistake for 203 error, was using Bearer authz instead of Basic.

```
@org = MyCompany
@authz = Basic My_Personal_Access_Token_Base64_with_colon_prefix

GET https://dev.azure.com/{{org}}/_apis/projects
Authorization: {{authz}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Bash script inferred from ado website to generate colon-prefix base64 of PAT:

```
pat=ThePersonalAccessTokenAsFromADO
b64pat=$(printf "%s"":$pat" | base64)
echo $b64pat
```