# Run pipeline using Azure REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-rest-api

As I see in the last version of documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2

To using this API

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.2-preview.1`

I need oauth2

`Authorization URL: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/authorize&response_type=Assertion Token URL: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/oauth2/token?client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer`

How to use this?

I know that Azure has several authorization methods, a large number of options on how to use them.

And to be honest, I am completely confused by them.

It is not clear how exactly to use them, when, what access to set for the user and what to send in requests?

If I try to generate token like this

`GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/0000000-0888-00000-be70-0000000/oauth2/v2.0/token Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 229 grant_type=password&username=[user]&password=[pass]&client_id=[clientID]&client_secret=[clientSecret]&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default`

I successfully get Baerer token. But when I using this token in

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=7.2-preview.1`

I have 203 status and of course my pipeline is not running

Comment: refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows, you need to generate PAT and pass it in Authorization: Basic {Base64-encode PAT} while making the POST call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PAT in Azure Devops and ensure it has **Build** - Read & execute permissions:
[image]

Then get this PAT and Base64 encode it, using:

```
$MyPat = 'yourPAT'

$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`:$MyPat"))
```

You can then pass this into your REST API headers like:

```
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic <base64-encode-pat>"
}
```

It should work after this.

Comment: Hi @dan
I generated PAT with full access
Then I converted PAT to Base64 using this
`Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MyPat))`
Then I send POST request and steel have the same response (203 status)

`POST https://dev.azure.com/*****/****/_apis/pipelines/**/runs?api-version=7.2-preview.1

Request Headers
Authorization: Basic an*************************************************==
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: VstsSession=*****
Content-Length: 0`

Comment: Maybe try following this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192108/authenticating-to-visualstudioonline-rest-api-with-personal-access-token-using-p

Seems you may need to add a leading colon to your PAT.


Also try checking the security settings for your pipeline and ensure that Queue builds is set to Allow

Comment: Yes, you're right, I didn't have rights in my pipeline. THX

Comment: And also yes, I didn't have ":" in my token

Comment: No problems. What was the specific group that you had to give permission to just for future reference? Or was it your own individual user?

Comment: The user had all rights, but for the pipeline (in pipeline settings) the user could only read